# Text out of \axis

Tags: nodes

I would like to `shift` text of nodes out of `axis` area like in the first image. If this is difficult to realize, would be nice also the solution in the second image, in which the right margin of area is shifted in order to let enough space for the text of the `node`.

[image]

[image]

The code I used is this:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{WHCs.dat}
Sample  y   y_err
5-Pa-Pr 0.520   0.10
6-Pa-Pr 0.465   0.05
7-Pa-Pr 0.768   0.16
5-Pa-S  0.517   0.10
6-Pa-S  0.562   0.20
7-Pa-S  0.794   0.35
\end{filecontents*} 

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar, ymin=0,
        bar width=15pt,
        x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east},
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        xtick = data,
        axis on top,
        enlarge x limits=0.35,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        symbolic x coords={5-Pa-Pr, 6-Pa-Pr, 7-Pa-Pr, 5-Pa-S, 6-Pa-S, 7-Pa-S},
        ymajorgrids]
   \begin{scope}
    \fill[brown] (rel axis cs:0,0.355) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,0.365);
    \fill[green] (rel axis cs:0,0.495) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,0.505);
    \fill[red] (rel axis cs:0,0.555) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,0.565);
    \path 
    node[anchor=east] at (rel axis cs:1,0.36) {Sand}  
    node[anchor=east] at (rel axis cs:1,0.50) {Clay}  
    node[anchor=east] at (rel axis cs:1,0.56) {Silty loam};  
    \end{scope}      
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit] table [x=Sample, y=y, y error=y_err] {WHCs.dat};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clip=false` to avoid clipping of content falling outside the axis. Then use `anchor=west` in place of `anchor=east` for those nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{WHCs.dat}
Sample  y   y_err
5-Pa-Pr 0.520   0.10
6-Pa-Pr 0.465   0.05
7-Pa-Pr 0.768   0.16
5-Pa-S  0.517   0.10
6-Pa-S  0.562   0.20
7-Pa-S  0.794   0.35
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        clip=false,
        ybar, ymin=0,
        bar width=15pt,
        x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east},
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        xtick = data,
        axis on top,
        enlarge x limits=0.35,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        symbolic x coords={5-Pa-Pr, 6-Pa-Pr, 7-Pa-Pr, 5-Pa-S, 6-Pa-S, 7-Pa-S},
        ymajorgrids]
   \begin{scope}
    \fill[brown] (rel axis cs:0,0.355) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,0.365);
    \fill[green] (rel axis cs:0,0.495) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,0.505);
    \fill[red] (rel axis cs:0,0.555) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,0.565);
    \path
    node[anchor=west] at (rel axis cs:1,0.36) {Sand}
    node[anchor=west] at (rel axis cs:1,0.50) {Clay}
    node[anchor=west] at (rel axis cs:1,0.56) {Silty loam};
    \end{scope}
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit] table [x=Sample, y=y, y error=y_err] {WHCs.dat};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]